# WDS Live Reloading enabled twice

Tags: javascript, debugging, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Idk why but all my code runs twice when I run webpack-dev-server(webpack serve)...
my folders path:

- dist
- src

  - js

    - app.js
    - loadBro.js
  - scss

    - main.scss
  - index.html

List item

here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app:'./src/js/app.js',
    loadBro: './src/js/loadBro.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer:{
    open:true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['app', 'loadBro'],
    }),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader']
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you already applied `plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: ...})` then no need add `<script src="bundle whatever u give here"></script>`

Comment: You're a saint! I've run in that exact error and have been search for 2 hours now…!

Comment: glad to hear that :)